# What private companies have launched a satellite to gather satellite imagery?

Tags: artificial-satellite, commercial, raw-data

Are there private banks or companies that have paid for access to up-to-date satellite imagery, whether through financing the satellite or purchasing the raw data?

Out side of pure research, what are some notable names? I am more interested in companies that financed the satellites, and trying to learn what they use the information for. Why did they make the investment? I am curious if wall street companies are using satellite data to predict market movements, based on the image data of ports around the world. This, coupled with shipping traffic data, might "give them an edge" on world production and market activity.

Probably not a very appropriate question for Space Exploration, so I am backing out a bit and wondering about companies that have financed satellite operation, which I understand may be too broad to give any answer to.

Comment: Only an imagery company would want raw data from an imagery satellite. Other companies would want normalized imagery data sets for regions they are interested in.

Comment: I am curious if wall street companies are using satellite data to predict market movements, based on the image data of ports around the world. This, coupled with shipping traffic data, might "give them an edge" on world production and market activity.